# In Titanium， how to add the view at the specified position

Tags: android, titanium

In Titanium， how to add the view at the specified position?like the method in android adk addView(view, index);

Answer (score 0):

```
var r_view = Ti.UI.createView({
     top:2,
         height:100,
     width:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
     borderColor:'#225A94',
     backgroundColor:'#EEF5FB',
     borderRadius:8,
     borderWidth:1
});

//Add in window name
win.add(r_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_view = Ti.UI.createView({
     top:20,
     left:20,
     height:200,
     width:200,
     backgroundColor:'#000000'
});

//Add this to window
win.add(new_view)
```